# React - Error: Target container is not a DOM element

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I just got started using React so this is probably a very simple mistake, but here we go. The following code throws me always the following message: **Error: Target container is not a DOM element.** Furthermore it indicates that there's something wrong with the last line (render). I'm working through a [tutorial](https://lingui.js.org/tutorials/react.html) for LinguiJS and I use their code so I'm confused why this is not working.

I tried replacing `render` by `ReactDOM.render` and adapted the import consequently, but I received the same error. Any help would be highly appreciated!

```
//index.js

import React from 'react'
import { render } from 'react-dom'
import Inbox from './Inbox.js'
import catalogCs from './locales/cs/messages.js'

import { I18nProvider } from '@lingui/react'

const catalogs = { cs: catalogCs };
const App = () => (
  <I18nProvider language="cs" catalogs={catalogs}>
    <Inbox />
  </I18nProvider>
)

render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'))
```

Second file:

```
//Inbox.js
import React from 'react'
import { Trans } from '@lingui/macro'
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom';


const Inbox = ({ messages, markAsRead, user }) => {
   const messagesCount = messages.length
   const { name, lastLogin } = user

   return (
      <div>
        <h1><Trans>Message Inbox</Trans></h1>

        <p>
          <Trans>
          See all <Link to="/unread">unread messages</Link>{" or "}
          <a onClick={markAsRead}>mark them</a> as read.
          </Trans>
        </p>

        <p>
          {
            messagesCount === 1
              ? `There's ${messagesCount} message in your inbox.`
              : `There're ${messagesCount} messages in your inbox.`
          }
        </p>

        <footer>
          Last login on {lastLogin}.
        </footer>
      </div>
   )
}

export default Inbox;
```

Comment: Does your html file has <div id='app' />? for document.getElementById('app')

Comment: Isn't that what `const App = () =>  ...` is doing? Besides that there is no <div id='app'></div>. I followed the tutorial, so that's kind of confusing to me :S

Comment: That is required step to add the div in html, without this ReactDOM.render() will not know where to mount the React Component.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to my question. It's rather simple; the  in index.html was `id=root`, thus I only had to change `render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'))` to `render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'))`